# Why dynamic routing is not working as expected in Nuxt js when data coming from vuex or localstorage?

Tags: vue.js, routes, local-storage, nuxt.js, vuex

I want each question that entered by the user to be turned to a link that leads to a page to discuss and comments on this question solely. So, I have a text area that takes user input (a question ) then save it to a localstorge with previous hardcoded data.
The hardcoded data are rendered properly to valid links to dynamic pages. But those from user input are not working. I checked many questions here I did not find a proper answer to this problem.  I want the input of user to work as a link . They all stored together and I am looping them together , so I expect them all to be working as links properly. But those from user do not work as expected:

```html
<table v-for="q in questions">
  <td>
    <tr class="border-dotted border-2 border-light-blue-200">
       <nuxt-link :to="`/questions/${q.id}`"> {{ q.question }}</nuxt-link>   
    </tr>
  </td>
</table>
```

Computed property to read from vuex:

```js
computed: {
  questions() {
    return this.$store.state.all;
  } 
}
```

Any help?

[image: First 6 questions are hardcoded and they work. The last one is from user and it is not working]

[image: The data from user is stored properly within the hardcoded data but not works as them]

[image: This link is working . It is hardcoded. I expect similar results from data coming from users]

[image: This link from user is not working]

[image: Console TypeError of undefined]

Comment: You have errors in your console most likely. Please check there.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I got TypeError of undefined. I updated my question and added a screenshot of this error above.

Comment: I totally did not get what you're trying to achieve here. On top of that, there is an error on some place that is not even given. A [repro] could be nice, on top of clearer instructions.

Comment: Thanks for editing. What I am trying achieve is: getting a question from the user. When the user submits a question, it shows a link that leads to a page that allows discussion of this question. I could achieve this for hardcoded data, but it did not works when the question is coming from the user via text area. I mean, the links not working. I have edited my question to show that and clarify my intention.

Comment: Do you intend to make something like a forum where you can post a question and let other people see/answer to it? Like a competitor to StackOverflow ?! :O Jokes aside, you will require a backend for this, to let the whole thing persist and generate UUID in the url like `https://mywebsite.io/questions/lskd1831` that you could then access by fetching all the written content persisted into a database.

Comment: In fact, yes it is a prototype for something like StackOverflow but for a very small scale. So I understand that this functionality cannot be done without backend and DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, if you want to have something looking like StackOverflow, with various created pages and question + answers, you'll need persisted data.
Vue is client only and therefore, if you have a created question, it'll stay on your own machine (other people will not see it).

So yeah, a backend with a database is required here.

---

If it's a small project, you could even maybe use an online service like Firebase to have a mongo-like quick and simple DB. Or any other cheap/free service. If you want to go more serious, you'll need to make your own backend. :)

Comment: Thanks, but for just prototyping purposes,  cannot I just make these links works for a demo? I mean what technically prevent this from working on my local machine?  I would be grateful for any sources on this.

Comment: If you want to have it for a demo on your machine (only), you can achieve it too. You'll need to have a form with various text inputs, once you submit it, you could push the data into an array and generate a URL, and pass the payload to the details page. Here is an example on how to have a list + details pages with data fetched from an API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585 In your case, rather than fetching it, you could generate it locally but achieve pretty much the exact same behavior.