# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weather') in nuxtjs api call

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I cannot get the result from the open Weather API,I get this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'weather'), but the error's gone when I move the v-list part to another page.

**code is below, any helps would be appreciated :**

```html
   
<template>
    <div>
        <v-row>
            <v-col sm="10" offset-sm="1" lg="8" offset-lg="2">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase title text-center my-5">weather forecast</h2>
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-btn color="primary" outlined class="mt-7" @click="showWeatherInfo">Show Info</v-btn>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                    <v-list>
                        <v-list-item-group>
                            <v-list-item>Weather: {{item.weather[0].main}}</v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item> temperature: {{item.main.temp}} ° C. </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item> humidity: {{item.main.humidity}} % </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item> wind: {{item.wind.speed}}m </v-list-item>
                        </v-list-item-group>
                    </v-list>
                </v-row>
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-btn color="primary" outlined class="mt-7">Go Back</v-btn>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
        }
    },
    methods : {
        async showWeatherInfo(){
            const item = await this.$axios.$get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=tehran&appid=${process.env.apiKey}`)
            console.log(item)
            return { item }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: instead of methods I think you need to use create()

Comment: @danihazler OP is using a method on a `click`, so totally fine. And if you're using Nuxt, you're better using either `asyncData()` or `fetch()` hooks.

Comment: Did you loaded the Vue CDN just for the example or are you actually loading it inside of your nuxt app? You can give a look to this answer to see an example on how to write a simple fetching component in Vue/Nuxt: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585 Also, please give a read to this one, it may be useful: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to use best practice to call API with AXIOS and you should observe reactivity in Vue.js that there are two points that will solve your problem:

1- You need to define a data object or Array like  `item:[]` and assign your response in `this.item` in your function that you called it `showWeatherInfo()`

2- You need to call your function in the mounted life cycle

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <v-row>
            <v-col sm="10" offset-sm="1" lg="8" offset-lg="2">
                <h2 class="text-uppercase title text-center my-5">weather forecast</h2>
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-btn color="primary" outlined class="mt-7" @click="showWeatherInfo">Show Info</v-btn>
                </v-row>
                <v-row>
                    <v-list>
                        <v-list-item-group v-if="item">
                            <v-list-item>Weather: {{item.weather[0].main}}</v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item> temperature: {{item.main.temp}} ° C. </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item> humidity: {{item.main.humidity}} % </v-list-item>
                            <v-list-item> wind: {{item.wind.speed}}m </v-list-item>
                        </v-list-item-group>
                    </v-list>
                </v-row>
                <v-row justify="center">
                    <v-btn color="primary" outlined class="mt-7">Go Back</v-btn>
                </v-row>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            
            item:[]

        }
    },
   
    methods : {
        async showWeatherInfo(){
            const response = await this.$axios.$get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=tehran&appid=${process.env.apiKey}`)
            this.item = response
            
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably fix your issue with this

```html
<v-list-item-group v-if="item">
```

The reason is that if you try to iterate on an object when it's empty, you will get an error.
Meanwhile, your `template` is synchronous so you'll need to just tell it that some stuff can be empty there and that it doesn't need to freak out.