# How to create dynamic route in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

By default, nuxt adds a route for each page in pages.

I want to make when going to the page e.g. project.local/id/ec29cjsa5fas512ik, the user goes to a page template and the Vue receives this ec29cjsa5fas512ik id from the url so it can make proper API calls later.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585 Nuxt's dynamic route + accessing `this.$route.params`.

Comment: Exactly! Nuxt's dynamic routes allows to make /page/:id thing with just an underscore in the beggining. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a dynamic page in Nuxt2 with the following file, eg.

```
/pages/details/_id.vue
```

then you'll have a path like `/details/:id`.

---

More info can be found here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-routes