# how to update url, but not render new view or component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

i want to make a dynamic url for my e-ticket website using vuejs 2

expectating url like this

```
https://e-tickets.com/movies/{movie-title}-{movie-id}
```

example

```
https://e-tickets.com/movies/black-panter-1203
```

### UPDATE

so i have a flow like this

1. when user click movie, it will push a url like this "e-ticket.com/movies/1203" first.
2. after render a view component, my page will hit an API to get movie detail (inc title, synopsis, etc), and parameter/payload API from movie id in URL
3. after that, API return a response. After get the response, router will change url like this "e-ticket.com/movie/black-panther-1203" but not reload page or something. just replace old url to new url like that

Comment: Can you show the code of what you have tried so far? Have you read the documentation on dynamic routing with vue-router? https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching

Comment: @Gabe i read it before. but i still dont know how to make like that. Im updated my thread

Comment: I think programatic routing is what you are looking for: https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort

Comment: You mainly want something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585) in a vanilla Vue project.