# How to make API call using axios in Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, symfony

I am trying to integrate/run existing Vue project in localhost but I am not getting any data on my website(i am not getting any error but data is not showing).

How can I get data ( home page)? Here is my vue.js code. Here is my code in the `home.vue` file:

```
  mounted() {
    this.filter = this.$route.query;
    this.page = this.$route.query.page ? this.$route.query.page : 1;
    this.type = this.$route.query.type ? this.$route.query.type : 2;
    this.myInfo = this.$store.getters.getProfile;
    this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      let self = this;
      const query = this.encodeSearchParams(this.filter);
      request(`/api/meet/list?${query}`, "GET")
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.length == 0) {
              self.noMore = true;
            }
            self.userList = [];
            if (self.page == 1) {
              self.userList = response;
            } else {
              self.userList.push(...response);
            }
          }).catch((error) => {

          });
    },
```

And here is my "Meetcontroler.php"(inside src/controller folder)

```
class MeetController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/meet/list", name="meetList", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function meetList(
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Fire up the Developer Tools and head over to the Network tab. What does it say there for the request?

Comment: You can use something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585

Comment: @JovanPerovic i am getting 500 error

Comment: Excellent, that's your starting point. Go to the Symfony logs and find what went wrong :)