# How to import or use js file configuration into any vue page in your nuxt app

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project of listing booking.

I have done all my API calls and configuration in `index.js` in the `store` folder.  I would link to display the listing gotten from the API call on my `listing.vue` page.

How do I print my retrieved data or make my `index.js` accessible anywhere in the app?

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "lisngbook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.1"
  },
```

Comment: What does your file directory looks like?

Comment: Hi, firstly please do not use `momentjs` anymore, it's a dead project. Use `date-fns` or any other alternatives listed on [moment's official website](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/). Then, it would be useful for us to know: 1. the content of your `index.js` file 2. the content of your `listing.vue` file 3. the object you're receiving from the backend so that we know how we can _massage_ it accordingly. Please also indent and highlight it as I did with your current question.

Comment: Images are unfortunately not allowed here. Please edit your question with your code as actual text.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix your `store/index.js` file I have to say, but as of right now it's not a valid JS file. Regarding the whole thing, I'm not sure if there is a given issue if your code works and you have the proper payload. A relevant next step would be to know how you want to display it in your `listing.vue` page. Your payload looks quite friendly and you could iterate on it with a `v-for` and access the various fields to your liking. What kind of issue do you face exactly?

Comment: i want to display it in this div " replace the image, description address.. by the data gotten from the API
 the dis play them in grid form

Comment: I did not understand your last comment sorry. How do you want to display it? Got some visual as an example?

Comment: i want to display it in the  listing page where all data got from the API is used to create  listings on that page " images up - title and description down in a 3-column grid form

Comment: We still have no idea what the` listing.vue` page looks like tbh. It's currently too broad of a question. You can have this [quick example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490633/8816585) on how to achieve some dynamic API injection into a markup. For the rest, it's a matter of CSS (flexbox, grid, etc...). We would need to know what you have already tried by yourself here and what is not working.

Comment: i think i found a solution for the first part of it
sln 1
- Test if the data is passing by adding "     <div>
  {{ this.$store.state.properties }}
</div> "

If all the data gotten are displaying

I used these 
export default {
  async asyncData({ store }) {

    return {
      properties: store.state.properties
    }
  },
}

then these to loop

Comment: You don't need `this` in the template. Otherwise, this is indeed a viable approach.

Comment: ok i get iy 

the problem is when in use it on the listing.vue page is displaying but if i use it in the homepage component "recently added" it will show me


Property or method "properties" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the 
data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: Let's focus on one issue at a time and also, please edit your question with the relevant material so that we can help you efficiently.

Comment: Sorry for that @kissu

1- i think I found the reason why it wasn't displaying in a component 
" needed to replace v-for="property in properties" :key="property.id" with v-for="property in $store.state.properties" :key="property.id"" when accessing it in a component

Comment: @kissu are you on Discord ??

Comment: Currently the project 
1- Receive Data from the APIs 
2- Display them on the listing.vue page
3- displays them on any app component

But I still have 2 major problem

Comment: 1- description: 
it's not displaying ( after or under the location 
i have tried this 
                                      <p v-html="property.description"></p>
                                    <p>{{ property.description }}</p>
but nothing is displaying 

2- Whenever i make change my project ", especially the script" my website always gives an error message of " can not read properties on undefine (reading 0) .at this point I need to re-run the project one more time. but I refresh the page it will still do that

Comment: I am on  Discord indeed (everything available on my profile). As for the rest, you should not use `v-html` and the rest, I guess we'll need more details or a narrowed down issue.

Comment: And yeah, `asyncData` is available only on pages. `fetch()` (the lifecycle) is available everywhere tho.

Comment: i have acctually use v-html and nomal second one of {{ property.description }} but no wan is given

Comment: Hard to help you here since we have no code/context. Let's make it efficient for the next round!